# Can't use SDL_ttf with mingw even though i've included it

Tags: c, sdl, mingw32

I've been making a chess game in SDL and i want to display some text when the player wins/loses, i've tried to import SDL_ttf, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm on windows and use MinGw to compile, this is how i write it currentlly

`gcc -o chess.exe chess.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf`

In my code i write `#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>`

but when i write and try to compile it with MinGw

```
if(TTF_Init()==-1) {
    printf("TTF_Init: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
    exit(2);
}
```

I get the following error

```
C:\Users\CurrentUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg0sFE3.o:test.c:(.text+0xd1b): undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Have anyone here had the same problem?

Comment: Error says about `test.c` while your build command uses `chess.c`. Consider posting actual build command with its *full* output.